# Entity Framework Code First Foreign Key different column key

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, foreign-keys

So, **Addresses** has a PK of **Id** and a foreign key of **EntityKey** which references the **Vendors** table's Id, because Vendors have Addresses for their physical buildings.

When I query Vendors, I'm not able to return an associated Address.

Note: I don't want to change the schema.

```
[Table("EE.Address")]
public partial class Address {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [StringLength(5)]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    public Guid EntityKey { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EntityKey")] 
    public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
    // EntityKey should be Vendor.Id
}


[Table("EE.Vendor")]
public partial class Vendor {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string AlternativeName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string VendorCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string TaxId { get; set; }

    public Guid VendorTypeKey { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentKey { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[Table("EE.Address")]
public partial class Address {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [StringLength(5)]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Vendor")]
    public Guid EntityKey { get; set; }

    public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
    // EntityKey should be Vendor.Id
}


[Table("EE.Vendor")]
public partial class Vendor {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string AlternativeName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string VendorCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string TaxId { get; set; }

    public Guid VendorTypeKey { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentKey { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Address")]
    public Guid AddressId {get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The thing is, EntityKey is the ForeignKey to the Vendor.Id so I tried this... and it's still not working.. I can't change the database schema

        [ForeignKey("Vendor")]
        public Guid EntityKey { get; set; }....

Comment: @JBWebservices, I edited my answer...sorry I missed that.

Comment: @JBWebServices, I just provided yet another edit, which I think should work for you.  Please try and let me know.